# How to have a dynamic predefined collection Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing an app that has two models: Document and Requirements. Each Document has a type, and depending on that type, a number of requirements. And Each Requirement has a status (done or not), and a description.

The thing is, the Document type and the Requirement description values are predefined, and every possible value should be stored in dynamic collections so the users could expand them.

The first solution I came up with was creating two additional models: DocumentType and ReqDescription, both with only one attribute called name with the value itself. Also, both models would have their own controller for Creating and Destroying any value from the collection and when the app starts they would have a number of predefined instances, so with a has_many relationship with their owners (Document for DocumentType and Requirement for ReqDescription), they'd play the role of dynamics collections.

```
DocumentType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :Documents
    ...
end
Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :DocumentType
end

ReqDescripcion < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :Requirements 
end
Requirement < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ReqDescription
end
```

Is there a better way to handle this issue? like a gem or something.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here.  The user may edit the ReqDescriptions?  A question - would they chose one and then want to slightly edit it?  Or do they just get the canned description every time?

Comment: The users can only add or remove ReqDescriptions, they can't edit. They get the descriptions depending on the type of the document they just created (The Create and Destroy actions of ReqDescription are for admin users.)